# Is there a worked example for neural network pruning for the Faster-RCNN architecture from TensorFlow's object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to find a worked example of neural network pruning for the Faster-RCNN architecture.

My core stack is Tensorflow 1.12, its object_detection API ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)) on Python3.5.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I came across some Neural Network Pruning repos (e.g. [link](https://github.com/alexfjw/jp-ocr-prunned-cnn), implementing NVIDIA's pruning paper with Taylor expansion [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06440) - looking the most promising however (a) implemented in Pytorch and (b) on classification networks rather than detectors).

I am also aware of the existence of a pruning functionality within TensorFlow under this package ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning)), but could only run an example found in the comments of the following StackOverflow question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064450/how-to-use-tf-contrib-model-pruning-on-mnist)) to train and prune (not thoroughly tested) a simple Neural Network for hand written digits classification using MNIST dataset.

I am looking for a worked example and not reporting any bugs or issues in code.

Can someone point to me a worked example of pruning Faster-RCNN -or other detectors- found on the TensorFlow's object detection API ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)), preferably using TensorFlow's pruning package ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning))?

Comment: p.s. Apologies if this is not the place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Pruning is orthogonal to the meta-architecture used for object detection. When we talk about the TensorFlow Object Detection API, it heavily relies on builders that read the config and create corresponding nets, classes etc. I believe you want to prune the feature extractor as the most heavy part. If so, you need to first prune some feature extractor from slim (let's say, [Inception-V2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v2.py)), give it a name,  add its pruned version to [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/models), adjust proto config and many more. Shortly speaking, you need to introduce a new type of feature extractor. But I am not aware of any existing examples on that.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your thoughts and pointing practical starting points. Inception-V2 looks like the best trade-off (thumps up for the suggestion!) of accuracy and speed for the Faster-RCNN of the model zoo [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) from my experiments as well .

The path of (1) using a pre-trained extractor/classifier compatible with the object detection api, (2) then pruning it and (3) finally perform some "operation" to glue it on a Faster-RCNN network was my initial thought. 
(continuing...)

Comment: (...continuing)
Going into more detail, this would be a first step but based on this paper [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325938560_An_Efficient_Object_Detection_Algorithm_Based_on_Compressed_Networks), the computationally "heavy" part of the network is the (4) feature fusing of the (5) the region proposal network with (1) the feature detector/classifier and not just (1).

Comment: (...continuing) So ideally we should aim for pruning both (1) and (4) of the network. I will try to do something practical at least for (1) and share a suggested solution. In the mean time it would be great if the community provided a worked example.

Comment: I am afraid writing such an example would require too much effort.